# XSL template structure for choosing latest event

Tags: templates, xslt, sorting, position, foreach

I have a list grouped by Region and it currently shows all the items for each city. I want to reduce to only the most recent advisory for each city.

I have tried to use an xsl:for-each statement but I am messing up the names/parameters.

List is called mlc
The list contains the fields:
Title
City
Region
Advisory
DateCreated
TT (calculated number field to find the number of minutes from the DateCreated to end of today which I intended to use the smallest to find the most recent)

I have the list grouped by Region and it currently shows all the items for each city. I want to reduce to only the most recent advisory for each city.

Comment: Could you post a sample of your XML, as that will make things clearer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a co-worker help me and the code goes like this. City is sorted ascending. Created is sorted descending.

`<xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::Row[1]/@City) or preceding-sibling::Row[1]/@City!=@City">`

Now each city is shown only once and it is the most recent advisory.